# Embedding mp3 in apk (for phonegap/jquery mobile build)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

i m developing a music app using phonegap/jquery mobile using aide for phonegap. I want embed some mp3 songs in the apk build. how can i do this.

Comment: just put your files somewhere in the www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @QuickFix. Put somewhere in the www folder.

For my case, the build process ignored folder starting with underscore ie "_mp3". I removed the underscore then it works.

Answer (score -1):

Put the files in the folder and use the Cordova Media API to play the audio

```
var media = new Media('audio.mp3');
media.play();
```

Documentation here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/doc/index.md